# How can we make a WCF service specific to an application?

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, wcf-security

Suppose I am having a WCF services that is hosted somewhere. Also there are two applciations APP1 and APP2. What I want is that only APP2 can consume my WCF service, not APP1. Even APP1 is also having service URL and EndPoints still it should be able to call any method of the service.

Say, in my service there is a method Method1. So if APP2 calls it, then it should return result. But when APP1 calls it, it should get exception or some validation message.

I was thinking about impersonation, but if APP1 gets the password then it'll also be able to fetch result from Method1.

**Is it possible in WCF? If yes then how can I implement it?**

Answer (score 0):

How about having an authentication key in the request parameter of your WCF method? You'll define a valid key in the configuration file of your APP2 (the one that should return result) and not in your APP1.

Comment: What if someone also added the same key in APP1, then APP1 will also be able to get data from service.

Comment: I suppose you wanted to use wsHttpBinding.

Comment: No, I am looking for a solution that when APP2 calls service method then it should return data, and when APP1 calls service method it should return some validation message. Hope, I'm clear now.

Comment: Clearly understood that from the beginning, and based from your requirement, I suppose it is best to use such an authentication key since it will technically solve your requirement, at least if you understand my suggestion.

Comment: If both the applications were in different servers, you may also use firewall, if you maintain the server that provides the WCF service.

Comment: could you please tell me more about "Authentication Key"?